# Represent UUIDv4 string as bytes16 in event topic

Tags: solidity, web3js, events, bytes, convert

I am trying to emit an Event with UUIDv4 `indexed` `string`.

Example contract:

```
contract EventEmitter {
    event ExampleEvent(string indexed id);

    function dispatchEvent(string memory _uuid) public {
        emit DebugEvent(_uuid);
    }
}
```

Because `string` can have an arbitrary length, Solidity creates a Keccak-256 hash of the value which ends up in the topic.

for UUID `85abe432-538e-4281-8697-85e18775df5c` the value is `0xd4796a1ffda94665a2d19bf19cb326dabce44288e3a53d53a2b60f4c9f411650`

So when I'm retrieving past events using web3, I'm unable to get the correct string value

I found this question [Bytes16 event topic not being decoded (or encoded?) correctly](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/66274/bytes16-event-topic-not-being-decoded-or-encoded-correctly)

Where UUID is represented as `bytest16`.
However I couldn't find a straightforward way to convert a `string` into `bytes16`.

Would appreciate any help.

Comment: It should be quite easy: remove the dash characters (`-`), convert the hex characters to its byte1 equivalent, you should have 16 bytes1, after concatenating you have a bytes16.